# SQL to identify customers who order more than m times within k days

Tags: mysql

I have a sales table in MySQL as follow:

```
CustomerID    OrderDate
101           2014-12-11
102           2014-12-13
101           2014-12-14
103           2014-12-15
...           ...
```

If I want to find out which customers who order more than 5 times within any 10 days, or more generally, m times within any k days, how should I do it? I've tried self join but can't get the result with any k days.

Comment: ten most recent days or any ten days?

Comment: What have you tried, where does it fail? This is not a 'Can you do my work for me' site.

Comment: Sorry. It's any 10 days. I've tried to self join the sales table and count the sales date, but couldn't get what I need.

Comment: Why not provide a representative data set and a desired result?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
SELECT customerID, OrderDate, COUNT(*) AS num, (SELECT OrderDate FROM table AS b WHERE b.OrderDate < t.OrderDate + INTERVAL 10 DAY ORDER BY OrderDate DESC LIMIT 1) AS EndDate
FROM table AS t
GROUP BY  customerID, EndDate
HAVING  OrderDate <= EndDate AND num >= 2
```

It will return all periods where customer had more than 5 orders. Please note that you will have more than one record for same customer if he had more than 5 orders in for example 2 or more periods. If you want one row per customer just wrap query with `DISTINCT` select

Comment: This may work but it's extremely slow due to the double sub queries. I've tried it with my database on mysql and I still couldn't get the results even after 20 minutes of waiting. Any way to do it without sub queries?

Comment: still too slow to get a result... wondering if I can get around without the sub query...

Comment: I've tried some different approaches without subquery but none of them gave me desired results :( how many records do you have in your table?

Comment: I've replaced `MAX` function with `ORDER BY DESC LIMIT 1`, so try if it's faster

Comment: Sorry it still doesn't work. Maybe the table is too large.

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work?

```sql
select x.CustomerId from (
    select CustomerID, count(CustomerID) as customerCount from table where OrderDate > DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 10 DAY)
) x
where x.customerCount > 5
```

I haven't had time to test it, specifically the date subtract part, but that sort of thing has worked for me in the past.

Comment: Sorry. I didn't specify in my original post. It's any given 10 days not 10 days from now.